# Database deploy automation

Tags: sql, sql-server, rails-activerecord

In my company the developers use migrations for the schema changes in the database server and for install new databases too. More precisely they use Active Record (Ruby version). They have a project for automate everything (the development, the deployment and all that stuff).

I'm a member of the infrastructure team (The DBA). In my personal experience (I was a Rails developer), I really never liked migrations because I like to have the control of the database changes. Will sound ugly, but I prefer to put the .SQL scripts of the schema change in a GIT version control instead of using migrations. (Even when I was a Rails developer).

In the past before I were the DBA, the development team has deployed applications with the migrations and the results were awful. Tables with all nullable fields, no foreign keys at all in the database, no indexes, wrong datatypes, all ugly things that you can imagine.

I want to help in that project, but I don't want to have a problem with the future databases that we'll have to deploy. Anyone has experience on this? How can I help the development team to use migrations or something automatable but doing it the right way for the database?